# Can I move "little o" into an exponent on an asymptotic bound

Tags: asymptotics, proof-verification

I want to make really sure that I am not making a mistake here, although I generally don't have problem with asymptotics.

I have proven that a certain function $f(n)\in o(2^n)$. Well actually I proved it is $O(n^\sqrt{n})\subset o(2^n)$. Which follows since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^\sqrt{n}}{2^n}=0$$

Based on my understanding of little o, it  is submultiplicative(i.e. $o(f)o(g)\subset o(fg)$). This implies then that $o(2^n)\subset 2^{o(n)}$. Or am I making a grave mistake here? Can I get the bound I am looking for another way?

Comment: Sorry, what is the bound you are looking for?

Comment: @EricAuld $O(n^\sqrt{n})\subset 2^{o(n)}$

Comment: Is your function $f$ such that $f>0$?

Comment: @EricAuld for sufficiently large n, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\epsilon(n)=o(n)$ but $\epsilon(n)\to+\infty$ for a function $\epsilon$. Then $2^{n-\epsilon(n)}$ is $o(2^n)$ but not $2^{o(n)}$.

For the desired bound: Suppose $f(n)$ is $O(n^{\sqrt{n}})$, equivalently $O(2^{\sqrt{n}\log_2n})$ with constant $C$. Then $f(n)\le C2^{\sqrt{n}\log_2n}\implies \log_2 f(n)=C'+\sqrt{n}\log_2n$ is $o(n)$ hence $f(n)$ is $2^{o(n)}$ ($f>0$ assumed).

Comment: Okay, and the second part? Is $O(n^\sqrt{n})\subset 2^{o(n)}$ or not?

Comment: +1 Great! exactly what I was looking for. The $n^\sqrt{n}$ scared me at first when I saw it in my calculation since I was expecting a subexponential bound to come out.

Comment: @TimSeguine Can you tell me what a subexponential bound is? Google hasn't helped. Thanks :)

Comment: @EricAuld Intuitively, subexponential means a growth class lower than any exponential growth class. Formally, $f(n)$ is subexponential if $\log f(n)$ is sublinear, i.e. $\log f(n)$ is $o(n)$ (note the base of the logarithm doesn't matter in this definition).